# Atribuir lista retornada do banco para um combobox

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu tenho um código HTML/PHP onde tem um campo lista que eu gostaria de fazer retornar os registros do banco.
Porém, fica aparecendo o campo ou variável no display da lista ao invés dos valores de BD.

Não consigo descobrir a causa do problema.

Na imagem abaixo reparem que aparece na lista de estados um trecho do código " . $linha['nome_estado']."

[image: Erro]
Abaixo, segue o trecho do código:

```
<td class="Label">Estado: </td> <!-- Aqui é uma FK -->
    <td class="Field"><select id="slct1" name="estado">
        <?php
            include "connector.php";
            $sql = "SELECT sigla_estado, nome_estado FROM estado;";
            $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
            echo "<option value=''>Selecione</option>";
            while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
                echo "<option value='".$linha['sigla_estado']."'>".$linha['nome_estado']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</tr>
```

Abaixo segue meu connector:

```
<?php
$Servidor = '*********';
$usuario = '*********';
$senha = '********';
$banco = '************';
mysql_connect($Servidor,$usuario,$senha) or die (mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db($banco) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: não que seja a causa do problema, mas a função `mysql_connect` não deveria estar atribuída a uma variável para ser passada como segundo parametro na função `mysql_query` por acaso ? outra coisa, após carregar a página, procure pelo código fonte através do navegador, como está usando uma função PHP dentro de um elemento HTML, as vezes, pode que o restante do código de erro (warning se houver) esteja por ali de qualquer forma.

Comment: Não deu para perceber o erro, porém tem uma pequeno detalhe no seu HTML onde o último </tr> deveria ser um </td>